# Stuck on Mocking ClaimsType.NameIdentifier

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, moq, xunit, asp.net-core-2.2

trying to get better at writing a unit test but have hit a roadblock, the controller using this repository only tries to get the user id if a user is signed in, I managed to use Moq and xUnit to setup the isAuthenticated without, but I can't seem to find a way to set the ClaimsTypes.NameIdentifier value. 
If I run the app it works fine but the unit test is just failing. any assistance would be helpful

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserRepository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetId()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value ?? "";
    }
}

public class UserRepositoryTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IHttpContextAccessor> _httpContextAccessor;
    private IUserRepository _sut;

    public UserRepositoryTests()
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        _sut = new UserRepository(_httpContextAccessor.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetIdIfUserIsSignedIn()
    {
        string id = new Guid().ToString();
        //_httpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.User.Claims).Returns(
        //    new Claim[]
        //    {
        //        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,id )
        //    }
        //    );

        _httpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            .Returns(true);

        //act
        var result = _sut.GetId();

        //assert
        Assert.Equal(result,id);
    }
}
```

the way it tried it keep throwing an exception on getID()

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `IUserRepository.GetId` method the only method call you have within is:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
```

that is exactly, and only, what you have to setup, but you haven't. This is the reason for:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

---

You could setup it using a fluent mock expression like:

```
_httpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(new Claim("name", "John Doe"));
```

---

*Copied from comments:*

This works because `.HttpContext` is a property (of the interface) whose compile-time type is a public non-sealed class with an accessible zero-parameter instance constructor. Then `.User` is a public overridable (in fact `abstract`) property whose compile-time type is a public non-sealed class with an accessible zero-parameter instance constructor. Then finally `.FindFirst` is a public overridable (in fact `virtual`) method. So all is good.

Note that the `Claim` class could not have been mocked in the same way. This is why

```
_httpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(It.IsAny<string>()).Value)
            .Returns("John Doe");
```

would **not have worked**; the `Claim` type does not have the relevant constructor, and the `.Value` property cannot be overridden.

I have checked all of these before posting the answer.

Comment: thank you for  the response it did the trick, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: This works because `.HttpContext` is a property (of the interface) whose compile-time type is a public non-sealed class with an accessible zero-parameter instance constructor. Then `.User` is a public overridable (in fact `abstract`) property whose compile-time type is a public non-sealed class with an accessible zero-parameter instance constructor. Then finally `.FindFirst` is a public overridable (in fact `virtual`) method. So all is good (see next comment).

Comment: (continued) Note that the `Claim` class could not have been mocked in the same way. This is why `_httpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(It.IsAny<string>()).Value).Returns("John Doe");` would not have worked; the `Claim` type does not have the relevant constructor, and the `.Value` property cannot be overridden.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I have checked all of these before posting the answer. This is indeed nice explanation so be free to edit my question and add it if you want. Tnx.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen- I appreciate the details feedback,  the solution that provided did work.  I cant put the screenshot here, but i have uploaded it to my one drive, but you can see it passing on the live testing I am using in visual studio 2019

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjjKG7B37iVBnPs0WCBIELbFgO1UAA